# Remove "#comments" from comments pagination url

Tags: comments, pagination

how can I remove the "#comments" behind the comments pagination link generally ?

At themoment it gives out links like: /comment-page-3/#comments
I wanna have it clrea like this: /comment-page-3/

Comment: Please read [ask]. Tell us what you have tried and what your research efforts are. _I wanna X._ is not a question.

Comment: I tryed nothing, because I have no plan how to remo this "#comments" generally ? Dont know where its definated

Comment: Then look at the source code in WordPress like everybody else.

Comment: I was googeling now about 1 hour but I didnt find any reference where this is definated

Comment: The **source code in WordPress**. You do have a copy of WordPress on your computer, right?

Comment: In the source code is only standing the navigation link...klicking this in comments this happens, waht I wrote above. So I dont know where this is defined...I think for reasons like this a forum ist there !

Comment: It seems to be based in " 

    wp-includes/link-template.php , Zeile 2850 perhaps its possible to filter it...but how...I really dont know...unfortunately !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your theme template is a call to `the_comments_pagination()`. If you would [look at the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cf571b12c166d9217fbcc67aded01399fc520ef9/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2894), you could find the declaration of that function:

```
function the_comments_pagination( $args = array() ) {
    echo get_the_comments_pagination( $args );
}
```

There are two things to note here:

1. This function is passing its call through to another function.
2. It accepts a parameter `$args`.

Looking at the called function `get_the_comments_pagination()` shows you that the markup is built using `paginate_comments_links( $args )`. So the `$args` are passed through again.

And in that function you can see what happens with the parameter: It is parsed against a default value.

```
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $max_page,
    'current' => $page,
    'echo' => true,
    'add_fragment' => '#comments'
```

In conclusion, you just have to change the call to the first function:

```
the_comments_pagination([ 'add_fragment' => '' ]);
```

Comment: Ahhhh I understang...ok...many thanks...so until now I only user the standrt navigation (without 1,2,3,4) because of the reason, that I dont know, how to reverse the numbers, becose they are count from back to fron and with the highes number they make duplicate content...So for that I will make an new question (sorry Iam new here, dont know exactly all rules)

Comment: To that one Questin more pleas: The headline "Comments Pagination" does even come from this. How to filter this that its away ? In the Template its not !

Comment: @RodneyHawk Again, see the source. It is the argument `'screen_reader_text'`.

Comment: Yes I know...i told before that that is in this . But how to filter it out ?

Comment: @RodneyHawk Pass it as an empty string to the arguments. There is no need to "filter it out".

Comment: I tryied like this but doesnt function: <?php the_comments_pagination([ 'add_fragment' => '', 'screen_reader_text' => '' ]);?>